# Htmlnode collection and parsing

Tags: html, parsing, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to extract the text contained in a webpage. So that I'm using a third pary tool Html Agility Pack. In that they mentioned:

```
HtmlWeb htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = htmlWeb.Load("http://www.msn.com/");

HtmlNodeCollection links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");
foreach (HtmlNode link in links)
{
Response.Write(link.Attributes["href"].Value + "<br>");
}
```

It is working for me to grab all other links contained in a page. But I want to get all the text data contained in that page. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, it's possible.  Download the source code for the HtmlAgilityPack and take a look at the Html2Txt sample project, particularly HtmlConvert.cs.  You can pretty much copy/paste their method into whatever it is you're doing.

Or, for that matter, compile the sample project as-is and set a reference to the binaries.  HtmlAgilityPack.Samples.HtmlToText.Convert() will do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

you are using an xpath selector there. If you select all nodes ("*") and then perform the foreach would it work?

PS: what programming language is this?